# Scala: How to always extract the same substring out from strings with different prefix and/or suffix

Tags: regex, scala

given the following strings...

```
val s0 = "objects"
val s1 = "/objects"
val s2 = "/objects(0)"
val s3 = "/objects(1)"
```

I need to extract the substring `objects`, regardless of any possible prefix and suffix. If the string always started with a slash and ended with `(N)`, then easiest solution would be

```
scala> s3.substring(1).substring(0, s3.indexOf("(") - 1)
res1: String = objects
```

How do I always extract the string `objects` with a regex (I suppose this is the way to go)?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you know the exact string that you want to extract, why do you need to extract it at all?

Comment: Do you just want to check whether a string contains the substring `objects`?

Comment: Was just an example to explain that I need to extract a string between `/`  and `(N)` (`/` and `(N)` might or might not be present).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below regex and get the string you want from group index 1.

```
^\/?(.*?)(?=(?:\(\d*\))?$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xP9dR0/1)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do this:

```
val pattern = """.*/(objects)\(\d+\).*""".r

val data = Seq("objects", "/objects", "/objects(0)", "/objects(1)")

val results = data.map{
    case pattern(obj) => obj
    case _ => "-"
}
```

Scala REPL:

```
results: Seq[String] = List(-, -, objects, objects)
```

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the delimiting characters allows for this use of `dropWhile` and `takeWhile`; for

```
val in = Seq("objects", "/objects", "/objects(0)", "/objects(1)")
```

then

```
in.map(i => i.dropWhile(_ == '/').takeWhile(_ != '('))
List(objects, objects, objects, objects)
```

A regular expression with grouping as already suggested proves more robust, scalable and general otherwise.